# Does HTML5 video source order matter?

Tags: html, video

I created a video page:

```
<video autoplay loop width="1280" height="720">
<source src="media/airplane720.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="media/airplane720.ogv" type="video/ogg">
Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video in WebM with VP8 or MP4 with H.264. 
</video>
```

Firefox 44 will not play or even display the no-browser-support message.
However, if I change the order - i.e. place the ogv file first, it works.

Questions:

a. Does the HTML5 video fallback method not work? what's the point then?

b. How can I check at run time - which video format is loaded in each browser? In Chrome --> developer tools --> network - I see that both mp4 + ogv files have downloaded (status=finished). Why is that? Shouldn't only one download? What's the point if everything downloads?

c. How do I check the same in Firefox?

Thanks,
K.

Comment: Hey did you actually figure this out ? I too have 3 types ogv webm and mp4 and it uses the first one that is playable not per se the best one? For example I would like chrome to use webm since it is smaller than ogv and mp4 but It only uses is if its before the others..:(

Answer (score 1):

a) The no-browser-support message has to do with the `<video>` tag, not with video file types. In case the TAG is not supported (no html5 support) then you should see the message.

b) You can check it through Javascript, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canPlayType

```
var obj = document.createElement('video');
console.log(obj.canPlayType('video/mp4')); // check the return value
```

c) ---

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am not sure if what I ask s clear. How come the video plays - only - if the order of the file formats is swapped? 
Isn't this the point of the fall-back method? Move to the next format if previous doesn't play...

Comment: Yes, that should be definitely the case, the browser should simply play one of the videos and skip any unsupported format. I guess the FF browser knows it can play mp4 videos but there's something in this mp4 file that causes FF to stop playing it. Maybe some unexpected audio or video codec in the mp4 container? Have you tried another mp4 file?